# OSError: Starting path not found (dotenv-0.21.0-py3.9.egg)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-dotenv

I'm developing a script in Python 3.9 that works perfectly on my personal PC. When I tried moving and running it on a server, which has an older python version, it gives me the following error:

[image: error]

Does anyone know how to fix this error?

I tried to install dotenv via pip manually, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Add `.env` file content

Comment: Also, from the error it shows it's also using Python 3.9, not "*an older python version*". The error also shows that dotenv is having trouble finding the .env file. Please [edit] to also show the file/folder structure and how you are running the script.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your errors (and code if any) as **text** rather than as a screenshot. On stack overflow images should not be used for text, see [*Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) and [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) for why. For instructions on formatting see *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)*. A [mcve] showing what you have tried that did not work would maximize your chances of getting help. See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

This could be the same issue than [there](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77068121/1676127), where the problem was using `python setup.py install` instead of `pip install .`. So it is a problem related to the project installation and not the python-dotenv installation.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should use Pylaucher, to start Pylaucher you must Use Shebang (#) in The Script Run Pylauncher Command. Then you will be able to run multiple versions of python in Windows without getting errors. There are too many methods you can use; I strongly suggest this one since has once worked for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).