# Get python-dotenv "OSError: Starting path not found" in a python package install using `setup.py install`

Tags: setuptools, setup.py, egg, python-dotenv

## Problem description

When working with environment vars, a `.env` file is used for development via python-dotenv. When the app is distributed (and so installed using `setuptools`), the env vars are provided by an other way of course.

The problem is after installing in a virtual env via `setup.py install`, launching a script that uses `load_dotenv` raises the error **OSError: Starting path not found**:

```bash
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dev/testpkg/venv/bin/run", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('testpkg==0.0.1', 'console_scripts', 'run')()
  File "/home/dev/testpkg/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 489, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/home/dev/testpkg/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2852, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/home/dev/testpkg/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2443, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/home/dev/testpkg/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2449, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/home/dev/testpkg/venv/bin/run.py", line 4, in <module>
    __import__('pkg_resources').run_script('testpkg==0.0.1', 'run.py')
  File "/home/dev/testpkg/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 666, in run_script
    self.require(requires)[0].run_script(script_name, ns)
  File "/home/dev/testpkg/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1469, in run_script
    exec(script_code, namespace, namespace)
  File "/home/dev/testpkg/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/testpkg-0.0.1-py3.8.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/run.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "/home/dev/testpkg/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dotenv/main.py", line 336, in load_dotenv
    dotenv_path = find_dotenv()
  File "/home/dev/testpkg/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dotenv/main.py", line 300, in find_dotenv
    for dirname in _walk_to_root(path):
  File "/home/dev/testpkg/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dotenv/main.py", line 257, in _walk_to_root
    raise IOError('Starting path not found')
OSError: Starting path not found
```

The solution to this problem would be to use `pip install .` which works fine.

I know that eggs are deprecated, but I would like to know if there is a solution to make this work using `setup.py install`?

## Full example

There's a minimal project to reproduce the error.

A fresh project installed in a virtual environment using Python 3.8 and a [src-layout model](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/package_discovery.html#src-layout).

### The project tree

```
root_project_dir/
 |--- .env
 |--- setup.py
 |--- src/
       |--- run.py
       |--- pkg/
             |--- __init__.py
             |--- mod.py
```

Of course the `.env` is only for local testing and is not aimed to be distributed.

The `run.py` script's `main()` function is the entry point of the app.

### `setup.py` content

```py
from setuptools import setup, find_namespace_packages

setup(
    name='testpkg',
    version='0.0.1',
    install_requires=["python-dotenv"],
    packages=find_namespace_packages(where='src'),
    package_dir={"": "src"},
    scripts=['src/run.py'],
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'run = run:main',
        ]
    }
)
```

### `run.py` content

```py
import os

from dotenv import load_dotenv

from pkg.mod import Mod

load_dotenv()

VAR = os.getenv('VAR')


def main():
    m = Mod(VAR)
    m.run()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

### `mod.py` content

```py
class Mod(object):
    def __init__(self, var):
        print("init with var:", var)

    def run(self):
        print("Ok I ran!")
```

### `.env` content

```
VAR=some text
```

## Reproduce the problem

### Install and run

Create and activate a virtual env:

```bash
python3 -m venv venv
source ./venv/bin/activate
```

#### test locally

Run locally works with the .env retrieved:

```bash
(venv) root_project_dir/$ pip install python-dotenv
(venv) root_project_dir/$ python src/run.py
init with var: some text
Ok I ran!
```

#### install the package and run

First install:

```bash
(venv) root_project_dir/$ python setup.py install
...
Using /home/dev/testpkg/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages
Finished processing dependencies for testpkg==0.0.1
```

Then run the entry point generates the error:

```bash
(venv) root_project_dir/$ run
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dev/testpkg/venv/bin/run", line 11, in <module>
...
  File "/home/dev/testpkg/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dotenv/main.py", line 300, in find_dotenv
    for dirname in _walk_to_root(path):
  File "/home/dev/testpkg/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dotenv/main.py", line 257, in _walk_to_root
    raise IOError('Starting path not found')
OSError: Starting path not found
```

At line 300, `path` value is `/home/dev/testpkg/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/testpkg-0.0.1-py3.8.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts` whereas `/home/dev/testpkg/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/testpkg-0.0.1-py3.8.egg` is of course a file.

Again, the solution to this problem would be to use `pip install .` which works fine.

I know that eggs are deprecated, but I would like to know if there is a solution to make this work using `setup.py install`?

Answer (score 0):

If other users have the same issue and just want to make it working,
as I said, a way to solve this problem is to use pip instead of `python setup.py install`:

```bash
(venv) pip install .
```

And voilà!

As you can see in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70019592/1676127), eggs are deprecated and replaced by using pip/wheels.

Answer (score 0):

Removing `.pytest_cache` and `__pycache__` folders might help. The problem occured to me after I renamed parent folder.